# What can I do if paid apps won't install in Software Center?

Tags: 14.04, software-center

I purchased and tried to install `Messenger-ubuntu` through the Software Center, but the installation gets caught in a loop:

[image: Software Center installation loop]

Other free apps will still install just fine, but I also noticed that `Recommendations` had switched off, and I'm unable to switch it back on (also just loops).

If I had to guess, it has something to do with my Ubuntu One password, as I had to change it to something more secure in order to purchase the app.

So I guess my question is two-fold:

1. I'd prefer to fix this myself, but I'm not sure where to begin. I've restarted the system, and completely uninstalled and reinstalled `Software Center` (with `apt-get purge` and `apt-get autoremove`), all to no avail. Even after reinstalling, it still had my install history and `Ubuntu One` account details. Is there another way to cleanly reset/reinstall `software-center` without breaking the system? What other troubleshooting steps or fix can I try?
2. Failing me fixing it myself, what channels can I pursue in order to get either a refund or support for the app? I contacted the developer, but they were totally uninterested in helping (and somewhat rude). Is Canonical worth contacting? How best do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I've resolved the issue to my own satisfaction, although whether or not future paid apps will work, I don't know short of purchasing another app - something I'm not willing to do right now.

For `Messenger-ubuntu`, the developer again got back to me (unprompted this time), this time providing me a link to download the .deb file to install directly. It was a surprise actually. Anyway, I installed the .deb package from the command line and the app works fine.

As far as `Software Center` recommendations failing to turn on, it was just as I suspected - my password change caused the fault. This was resolved by opening `Passwords and Keys`, clicking `Login` in the left-hand panel, and deleting the entry for `Ubuntu One`. I then reopened Software Center and entered my Ubuntu One credentials again. It logged in and loaded my recommendations just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you got the .deb file the you can install it by

open Terminal and navigate to the folder containing the .deb file
and

`sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
sudo apt-get -f install`

a similar app is available on http://messengerfordesktop.com/#download

and try above step to install it

Comment: I appreciate the reply, but unfortunately that still leaves me with an app that I've paid for that doesn't work. What's more, Software Center still won't show software recommendations, suggesting something deeper is broken. I'd like to try and rectify the problem I have rather than just work around it.